# Error Help: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I'm having trouble debugging my code.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def compare(self, other):
        x1 = self.x
        y1 = self.y
        x2 = other.x
        y2 = other.y
        n = 512
        if (x1 == x2) and (y1 == y2):
            return 0
        found = False
        while found == False:
            if ((x1 // n) != (x2 // n)) or ((y1 // n) != (y2 // n)):
                found = True
                c1 = ((x1 // n), (y1 // n))
                c2 = ((x2 // n), (y2 // n))
            else:
                if x1 >= n and x2 >= n:
                    x1 = x1 - n
                    x2 = x2 - n
                if y1 >= n  and y2 >= n:
                    y1 = y1 - n
                    y2 = y2 - n
                n = n / 2
        if c1 == (0, 1):
            e1 = 1
        if c1 == (1, 1):
            e1 = 2
        if c1 == (0, 0):
            e1 = 3
        if c1 == (1, 0):
            e1 = 4
        if c2 == (0, 1):
            e2 = 1
        if c2 == (1, 1):
            e2 = 2
        if c2 == (0, 0):
            e2 = 3
        if c2 == (1, 0):
            e2 = 4
        if e1 > e2:
            return 1
        if e2 > e1:
            return -1

    def dist(self, other):
        x = abs(self.x - other.x)
        y = abs(self.y - other.y)
        if x >= y:
            return x
        else:
            return y

    def getx(self):
        return self.x

    def gety(self):
        return self.y

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.compare(other) == -1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.getx and self.y == other.gety

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self < other or self == other

from Point import Point

class PointSet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def add(self, point):
        count = 0
        found = False
        if self.list == []:
            self.list.append(point)
            found = True
        while not found:
            for x,y in self.getpoints():
                if point.compare(Point(x, y)) == -1:
                    self.list.insert(count, point)
                    found = True
                    return count
                else:
                    if count == len(self.list)-1:
                        self.list.append(point)
                        found = True
                        return count
                    count = count + 1

    def NN(self, query):
        count = 10000
        trace = ()
        if self.list == []:
            return None
        for x,y in self.getpoints():
            if query.dist(Point(x, y)) < count:
                count = query.dist(Point(x, y))
                trace = (x, y)
        return trace

    def ANN(self, query):
        count = 0
        if self.list == []:
            return None
        for x,y in self.getpoints():
            if query.compare(Point(x, y)) == -1:
                return self.list[count], self.list[count+1], self.list[count-1], self.list[count-2]
            else:
                count = count + 1

    def getpoints(self):
        return [(i.x, i.y) for i in self.list]
```

When I try and run my tests, most of them come back with an error saying 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getx'. I'm not sure why this error keeps coming up. Here is my test code.

```
import unittest
from Point import Point
from PointSet import PointSet

class TestPointSet(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        coords = [ 
            (300, 800),
            (12,720),
            (75,660),
            (150,550),
            (605 , 810),
            (900, 640),
            (100, 390),
            (300, 400),
            (80, 100),
            (260, 30),
            (400, 25),
            (1000, 450),
            (940, 400),
            (990, 410),
            (800, 280)
            ]

        self.pt_list = [Point(x,y) for x,y in coords]

    def test_new_point_set(self):
        pts = PointSet()
        pts.add(Point(0,0))
        pts.add(Point(0,1023))

    def test_pointset_is_ordered(self):
        pointset = PointSet()
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                pointset.add(Point(i* 8+1,j * 16 - 1))

        for i in range(100-1):
            assert(pointset.getpoints()[i] < pointset.getpoints()[i+1])

    def test_pointset_is_ordered2(self):
        pts = PointSet()
        pts.add(self.pt_list[3])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[10])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[6])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[11])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[1])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[4])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[7])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[14])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[8])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[5])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[13])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[9])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[12])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[0])
        pts.add(self.pt_list[2])

        for i,p in enumerate(pts.getpoints()):
            self.assertEqual(p, self.pt_list[i])

    def test_NN(self):
        pointset = PointSet()
        for i in range(15):
            for j in range(15):
                pointset.add(Point(i * 64, j * 64))

        for i in range(15):
            for j in range(15):
                nn = pointset.NN(Point(i * 64 - 31, j * 64 + 31))
                assert(nn.getx() == i * 64)
                assert(nn.gety() == j * 64)

    def test_ANN(self):
        ps = PointSet()
        for p in self.pt_list:
            ps.add(p)
        self.assertEqual(ps.ANN(Point(129, 390)), self.pt_list[6])
        self.assertEqual(ps.ANN(Point(1000, 512)), self.pt_list[5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The traceback needed to indented to be readable.

```
Traceback:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\TestPointSet.py", line 60, in test_pointset_is_ordered2
  self.assertEqual(p, self.pt_list[i])
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 820, in assertEqual
assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 810, in _baseAssertEqual
if not first == second:
File "C:\Users\\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\Point.py", line 67, in __eq__
return self.x == other.getx and self.y == other.gety
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getx'
```

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by traceback.

Comment: Well, you get an error, but presumably it says more than just `'tuple' object has no attribute 'getx'`.  The traceback is a bunch of lines with information about what file the line was in, what line it was, etc.  It starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and will end with the error that you gave above.

Comment: Oops, ya thats probably important lol. Traceback is in __eq__: return self.x == other.getx and self.y == other.gety it's in the point class

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pointset.NN returns a tuple, so nn is tuple, set here:

```
 for x,y in self.getpoints():
        if query.dist(Point(x, y)) < count:
            count = query.dist(Point(x, y))
            trace = (x, y)  # TRACE IS A TUPLE
 return trace
```

change to:

```
trace = Point(x, y)
```

And pointSet.getpoints returns a list of tuples:

```
 return [(i.x, i.y) for i in self.list]
```

change to

```
return self.list
```

Though this seems intentional, since self.list in pointSet is already a list of points. Are you sure you want them to be points?

Comment: Thanks! Changing the trace seemed to get the pointset.NN test through. Thanks a lot. Also, getpoints() was intentional.