# local variable 'e2' referenced before assignment Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with some errors my code keeps creating. I don't understand the errors because for error 1: e2 is assigned before it is reference. Also I don't think I passed any tuples through __ eq __. Thanks!

```
class Point:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def compare(self, other):
    x1 = self.x
    y1 = self.y
    x2 = other.x
    y2 = other.y
    n = 512
    if (x1 == x2) and (y1 == y2):
        return 0
    found = False
    while found == False:
        if ((x1 // n) != (x2 // n)) or ((y1 // n) != (y2 // n)):
            found = True
            c1 = ((x1 // n), (y1 // n))
            c2 = ((x2 // n), (y2 // n))
        else:
            if x1 >= n and x2 >= n:
                x1 = x1 - n
                x2 = x2 - n
            if y1 >= n  and y2 >= n:
                y1 = y1 - n
                y2 = y2 - n
            n = n / 2
    if c1 == (0, 1):
        e1 = 1
    if c1 == (1, 1):
        e1 = 2
    if c1 == (0, 0):
        e1 = 3
    if c1 == (1, 0):
        e1 = 4
    if c2 == (0, 1):
        e2 = 1
    if c2 == (1, 1):
        e2 = 2
    if c2 == (0, 0):
        e2 = 3
    if c2 == (1, 0):
        e2 = 4
    if e1 > e2:
        return 1
    if e2 > e1:
        return -1

def dist(self, other):
    x = abs(self.x - other.x)
    y = abs(self.y - other.y)
    if x >= y:
        return x
    else:
        return y

def getx(self):
    return self.x

def gety(self):
    return self.y

def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.compare(other) == -1

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.getx and self.y == other.gety

def __le__(self, other):
    return self < other or self == other

class PointSet:
def __init__(self):
    self.list = []

def add(self, point):
    count = 0
    found = False
    if self.list == []:
        self.list.append(point)
        found = True
    while not found:
        for x,y in self.getpoints():
            if point.compare(Point(x, y)) == -1:
                self.list.insert(count, point)
                found = True
                return count
            else:
                if count == len(self.list)-1:
                    self.list.append(point)
                    found = True
                count = count + 1

def NN(self, query):
    count = 10000
    trace = ()
    if self.list == []:
        return None
    for x,y in self.getpoints():
        if query.dist(Point(x, y)) < count:
            count = query.dist(Point(x, y))
            trace = Point(x, y)
    return trace

def ANN(self, query):
    count = 0
    if self.list == []:
        return None
    for x,y in self.getpoints():
        if query.compare(Point(x, y)) == -1:
            (x1, y1) = self.getpoints()[count]
            (x2, y2) = self.getpoints()[count+1]
            (x3, y3) = self.getpoints()[count-1]
            (x4, y4) = self.getpoints()[count-2]
            p = min(query.dist(Point(x1, y1)), query.dist(Point(x2, y2)), query.dist(Point(x3, y3)), query.dist(Point(x4, y4)))
            if p == query.dist(Point(x1, y1)):
                return Point(x1, y1)
            if p == query.dist(Point(x2, y2)):
                return Point(x2, y2)
            if p == query.dist(Point(x3, y3)):
                return Point(x3, y3)
            if p == query.dist(Point(x4, y4)):
                return Point(x4, y4)
        else:
            count = count + 1

def getpoints(self):
    return [(i.x, i.y) for i in self.list]
```

Here is my test code

```
import unittest
from Point import Point
from PointSet import PointSet

class TestPointSet(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    coords = [ 
        (300, 800),
        (12,720),
        (75,660),
        (150,550),
        (605 , 810),
        (900, 640),
        (100, 390),
        (300, 400),
        (80, 100),
        (260, 30),
        (400, 25),
        (1000, 450),
        (940, 400),
        (990, 410),
        (800, 280)
        ]

    self.pt_list = [Point(x,y) for x,y in coords]
def test_new_point_set(self):
    pts = PointSet()
    pts.add(Point(0,0))
    pts.add(Point(0,1023))

def test_pointset_is_ordered(self):
    pointset = PointSet()
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            pointset.add(Point(i* 8+1,j * 16 - 1))

    for i in range(100-1):
        assert(pointset.getpoints()[i] < pointset.getpoints()[i+1])

def test_pointset_is_ordered2(self):
    pts = PointSet()
    pts.add(self.pt_list[3])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[10])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[6])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[11])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[1])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[4])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[7])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[14])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[8])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[5])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[13])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[9])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[12])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[0])
    pts.add(self.pt_list[2])

    for i,p in enumerate(pts.getpoints()):
        self.assertEqual(p, self.pt_list[i])

def test_NN(self):
    pointset = PointSet()
    for i in range(15):
        for j in range(15):
            pointset.add(Point(i * 64, j * 64))

    for i in range(15):
        for j in range(15):
            nn = pointset.NN(Point(i * 64 - 31, j * 64 + 31))
            assert(nn.getx() == i * 64)
            assert(nn.gety() == j * 64)

def test_ANN(self):
    ps = PointSet()
    for p in self.pt_list:
        ps.add(p)
    self.assertEqual(ps.ANN(Point(129, 390)), self.pt_list[6])
    self.assertEqual(ps.ANN(Point(1000, 512)), self.pt_list[5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and my Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\TestPointSet.py", line 35, in test_pointset_is_ordered
pointset.add(Point(i* 8+1,j * 16 - 1))
File "C:\Users\n\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\PointSet.py", line 15, in add
if point.compare(Point(x, y)) == -1:
File "C:\Users\\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\Point.py", line 44, in compare
if e1 > e2:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e2' referenced before assignment


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\n\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\TestPointSet.py", line 59, in test_pointset_is_ordered2
self.assertEqual(p, self.pt_list[i])
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 820, in assertEqual
assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 810, in _baseAssertEqual
if not first == second:
File "C:\Users\\Desktop\\skeleton (5)\Point.py", line 67, in __eq__
return self.x == other.getx and self.y == other.gety
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getx'
```

Comment: @AMACB How will this help? Your if statements never get executed, that's why you don't initialize the `e2` variable.

Comment: You only set `e2` in your `if` statements which are not always run.

Comment: Why? shouldn't e1/e2 be defined since it only escapes the while loop after c1 and c2 are created. Any x or y's can't be greater than 1023, so the only possible outcomes for c1 or c2 should be (0,0) (1,0) (1,0) (1,1). It's like graph quadrants.

Comment: `n = n / 2` is doing true division, not floor division; `n` will be a `float` when that line first executes, which will allow for subtle floating point errors all over (and corrupt other types `n` interacts with; even if floor division is used, the result will be a `float` with a `.0` for the decimal, not an `int`). You want `n = n // 2` (or for brevity, `n //= 2`). Also, I'm not as confident as you off-hand that `c1` and `c2` are limited to `(0,0) (1,0) (1,0) (1,1)`, but it's late, and I could be misreading.

Comment: All that c1/c2/e1/e2 stuff at the bottom is just `return 1 if c1[1] < c2[1] or c1[0] > c2[0] else -1`. And it seems possible that they might be equal, which you don't handle (returning `None` by default).

Comment: This question looks almost identical to https://stackoverflow.com/q/35762183/1870151

Answer (score 0):

You define e1 and e2 only in particular cases, when the conditions of your first if statements are met. And even then, you do not define both e1 and e2.
So your code has no chance of working correctly as is.

You can change your code to define e1 and e2 at the top of your function:

```
def compare(self, other):
    e1, e2 = 0,0
    x1 = self.x
    y1 = self.y
    x2 = other.x
    y2 = other.y
    n = 512
    if (x1 == x2) and (y1 == y2):
        return 0
    found = False
    while not found:
```

Also note that `while not found` is clearer and more pythonic than `while found == false`.

Your `_eq_` function is incorrect as you do not call the functions. Change it to:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.getx() and self.y == other.gety()
```